# Run 16.04.1 media from RAM

Tags: 16.04, live-usb

I've downloaded the latest ISO for Ubuntu 16.04.1 (ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso) and made a bootable thumbdrive.  Is there any way I can run the media from RAM?

I was hoping for something similar to grml's toram option:
`grml toram - Copy the whole CD/medium to RAM and run from there`